# photo_id of each image for link inside foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

What I'm trying to do is get the photo_id='.$pid.' of each photo for the link wrapped around them inside the foreach loop.

I tried $image['photo_id'] but that didn't work it just printed image symbols. I then wrapped a separate foreach loop around the current one and that duplicated the amount of images. I'm new to using the foreach loop with arrays and keys so still trying to get my head around it.

```
$images = array();
while ($rowhhh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulthhh)) {
  $images[] = $rowhhh['photo_imagedata'];
  $photo_id[] = $rowhhh['photo_id'];
}

foreach ($images as  $image) {
if($photo_num==1){
echo '<a href="photo.php?photo_id='.$pid.'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:200px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" /></a>';
}else{
echo '<a href="photo.php?photo_id='.$pid.'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:100px;height:100px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" /></a>';
}
}
```

Comment: Where are `$photo_num` and `$pid` being set?

Comment: Hi, `$photo_num` has nothing to do with the question, but it is set in the query I just didn't include it and the `$pid` is not yet set at all. That is where I need to add the photo's array, but have no clue how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd use the `$images` var as a multidimensional array to store the ID and the Data of each image. Then, you can access both of these bits of information easily in your `foreach()` loop.

```
$images = array();
while ($rowhhh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulthhh)) {
  $imageArray = array(
       'data' => $rowhhh['photo_imagedata'],
       'id' => $rowhhh['photo_id']
  );

  $images[] = $imageArray;
}

foreach ($images as  $image) {
    if($photo_num==1){
        echo '<a href="photo.php?photo_id='.$image['id'].'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:200px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image['data']) .'" /></a>';
    }else{
        echo '<a href="photo.php?photo_id='.$image['id'].'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:100px;height:100px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image['data']) .'" /></a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic @thebluefox, Just what I needed. Hopefully this question and answer will help others. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure @Gateway - glad I could help.